# Strange icon in Word prevents proper text alignment

Tags: microsoft-word

In the ruler in Word, I see a pair of strange icons as shown in this image:

[image]

(the black grid-like icons). Depending on whether they are moved left or right the text that the cursor is placed next to is visible or is not and the other text moves left or right. Does anyone know how to remove those icons, which are not normally visible?

Comment: You should have a Table Design and another Layout tab on the right side of your Ribbon. Click on the Layout tab and check the box to view Gridlines on the left end of the tab. That can help you see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those icons should indicate that your cursor is within a table cell, and these represent the locations of the vertical boundaries between columns. Moving these resizes the columns, so some text in the cell may be obscured if it no longer fits inside.

Note that the table may not have actual *lines* drawn at these boundaries. Turn on "Show non-printing characters" to see some of the table-specific stuff in the document.

If you don't need the table and just somehow ended up with one (either by accident, or because you're using a document you received from someone else), just grab the text from the table and copy it outside for everything to behave as usual (then select and delete the table).